# MacBook Pro 2016 won't charge even on power adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, power

I'm using the [CalDigit USB-C](http://www.caldigit.com/usb-3-1-usb-c-dock/) Dock and the Mac said it is using the power adapter, but my battery is slowly draining:

[image]

I did an SMC reset and reset PRAM (NVRAM) but still won't charge.

Why isn't my Mac charging?

Comment: Test it with [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/)

Comment: *Which* power adapter are you using?  What are the specs of the power adapter you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the USB-C I was using is bad. I swapped the cable out for a different one, and the laptop started charging again through the dock.